# How to configure custom login page with Azure Active directory authentication in ASP.NET MVC 4.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am using Azure Active directory to authenticate the users. When I click on OpenConnectId in home page, it is getting redirected to Microsoft login page. Are there any options to use custom login page instead and may be call the authentication API from here.

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "xxxx",
                Authority = "xxx",
                RedirectUri = "Account/login",

            });
```

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: No. I didn't find any alternate.